# Bigger-on-the-inside multi-dimensional alien/precursor storage device

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much about the story in which this comes up, except for the aforementioned device.  It feels like a scene-setting bit of a larger story rather than an actual MacGuffin, though I think it shows up more than once.

The device is a fairly non-descript approximately cuboid block, either alien or possibly precursor technology.  It has the property that it can extrude an array of similar cubes, of the same or fractional smaller size, from any of its faces.  Each of these cubes can either be opened - and it might contain something - or it in turn can extrude another array of cubes from *its* faces.  And so on.  A specific pattern needs to be discovered to open each cube, it's not simply a matter of extending a group and opening them in turn.

It is being investigated by some scientists who are trying to find and classify all the objects stored in it.  The first time it is encountered, the viewpoint character finds an array extending out through the room/lab's door into the adjacent hallway.

I think I read this in the early 1990s, or at least before 1998.

Comment: It seems like the mildly absurdist kind of thing that Banks might have come up with, but no.  Another guess was Zelazny, based on the similarity to the Rhennius machine (*Doorways in the Sand*), but again no.

Comment: Sounds like something I remember from a Terry Pratchett Discworld book, but I can't remember which one at the moment.

Comment: It's too faint a recollection to put in the question, but have a faint recollection that one of the items found might have been a preserved foot.

Comment: @mwarren I did investigate that as a possibility - again the sensibility fits - but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It sounds like the Cabinet of curiosity https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Cabinet_of_Curiosity, but I'm failing to find which book at the moment.

Comment: @mwarren : I assume The Luggage ate it.  No competitors allowed.

Comment: If we were talking about movies, this also sounds like something from the *Hellraiser* series - I don't know if there are novels in this universe but I wouldn't be surprised.  There's at least comic books for sure.  And there's so many variations on how that cube thing works I wouldn't doubt that at least one of them matches this description...

Comment: Precursor Prolog!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is quite possibly the "[Cabinet of Curiosity](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Cabinet_of_Curiosity)" (so yes, Discworld, from "Making Money").

> Moist von Lipwig:- "...Er, a drawer about a hundred yards long has just slid out of a box about fourteen inches square". And all along the sides of this hundred yard length are more drawers.And one of those has just slid out to a hundred yards' length at right angles to the first drawer. And guess what...

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Well done +1

Comment: My first thought as well, but it was 2007 whereas OP said pre-1998. But, beyond that, it certainly ticks all the boxes. The wizards were researching is. The bacon sandwich discussion is definitely Pratchett at his finest.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Good point about the date, I didn't think to check that.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, right.  The more I think about the question, the less likely Pratchett seems to be the correct answer (after all the cabinet has drawers instead of extruding more cubes etc).

Comment: The question sounds like mixed up bits of 2010: Odyssey Two (Clarke) and Making Money (Pratchett)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "fourteen inches cubed"?

Answer (score 13):

The description sounds fairly similar to what E.C. "Oscar" Gordon called a "foldbox" in *Glory Road* by Robert A. Heinlein.  The novel was originally published in 1963, but was reprinted several times in paperback, including at least once in the 1980s.

The foldbox wasn't a major maguffin for the story, but figured prominently in an accident early on (hint: don't let your foldbox sink in deep mud).

In compact form, it was a cube about the right size to carry on a person's back (with shoulder straps attached), but any side could open out, and that opened out side could open out again -- it could grow to the size of a wardrobe, a shipping container, or perhaps even a warehouse, and the inside of each fold-out was at least as big as a box that exterior size.

Comment: This doesn't really fit.  There's no group studying the foldbox, and it's not an ancient artifact; they're in common use in that society.  Also, the sides don't extrude: "kept right on unfolding its sides and letting them down".